# Scrollbar listener for popup div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(window)
.scroll(UpdateTableHeaders)
.trigger("scroll");
```

This trigger when main scroll bar moves. But I need to trigger it when the scroll bar of my popup div is moved. What should I use in place of window? Or any other way?

Comment: Instead of `window`, refer the pop-up element in the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling:

```
$(window).scroll(UpdateTableHeaders);
```

..which listens for a scroll on the main window, specify which scrollbar to listen for this way:

```
$("#myPopupDiv").scroll(UpdateTableHeaders);
```

Comment: Please consider adding more detail to your answer.